# Fourier transform of time-shifted complex conjugate

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-analysis

I want to do a Fourier transform of a time-shifted complex conjugate function,

$\exp(iat)\bar{f}(t)$

where $a$ is a real, positive constant. If the Fourier transform of the original function is

$\exp(iat)f(t) \rightarrow F(\omega-a)$

then does it mean that

$\exp(iat)\bar{f}(t) \rightarrow \bar{F}(-\omega-a)$

or is it

$\exp(iat)\bar{f}(t) \rightarrow \bar{F}(-\omega+a)$

What physical differences are there between the two solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $\bar{f}(t)$ corresponds to $\bar{F}(-\omega)$. There are two (reasonable) options to determine the Fourier transform of $e^{iat}\bar{f}(t)$. The first is to define a function

$$g(t)=e^{-iat}f(t)\Longleftrightarrow G(\omega)=F(\omega+a)$$

from which

$$\bar{g}(t)=e^{iat}\bar{f}(t)\Longleftrightarrow \bar{G}(-\omega)=\bar{F}(-\omega+a)$$

follows. The other way is to transform $\bar{f}(t)$, and then shift the result by replacing $\omega$ with $\omega -a$:

$$\bar{f}(t)\Longleftrightarrow \bar{F}(-\omega)\\
e^{iat}\bar{f}(t)\Longleftrightarrow \bar{F}(-(\omega-a))=\bar{F}(-\omega+a)$$

So your second solution is correct. The difference between the two is that the correct solution has a spectrum centered at $\omega=a$, whereas the spectrum of the incorrect first solution is centered at $\omega=-a$.